# Using svg for image annotation

Tags: html, svg, raphael, jquery-svg

Can any one please give me some clarification on this:

I have to do some annotations on images like measurements, mark and text. Is this possible with SVG?
Do we need to install any external plugins to work with SVG in a web browser?
Will it be supported by mobile browsers?
what are the advantages of SVG over HTML5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Question**: I have to do some annotations on image like measurement,mark and text. How can it possible with svg?

**Answer**: This is possible using a combination of SVG, which when embedded in HTML becomes part of the DOM, and JavaScript to manipulate the SVG elements just as you would with any HTML element and JavaScript.

**Question**: Do we need to install any external plugins to work svg in a web browser?

**Answer**: No, most modern browsers render SVG.

**Question**: Will it support mobile browsers?

**Answer**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics#History_of_SVG_mobile_support

**Question**: what are the adventages of svg over Html5?

**Answer**: SVG is part of the DOM, which means it can be styled by CSS, manipulated with JavaScript, animated, etc.. Html5 Canvas is a JavaScript API which allows us to draw programatically. This means that SVG is nice for quick sleek graphics and can also be created with commercial or open-source SVG Editors. SVG can be animated or interacted with via JavaScript and styled via CSS. With the HTML5 Canvas you must use the JavaScript API to give life to your canvas. HTML 5 Canvas is higher difficulty curve, but can be much more robust than SVG ([Chrome Experiment](http://www.chromeexperiments.com/webgl/)).